Google ads, display network adGroups audience_setting error
i try to create an adgroup by REST api request.
payload is this
{"operations":[{"create":{"status":"ENABLED","name":"Adset","type":"DISPLAY_STANDARD","campaign":"customers/id/campaigns/id","optimizedTargetingEnabled":true,"audienceSetting":{"useAudienceGrouped":true}}}]}
{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Request contains an invalid argument.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.ads.googleads.v14.errors.GoogleAdsFailure","errors":[{"errorCode":{"contextError":"OPERATION_NOT_PERMITTED_FOR_CONTEXT"},"message":"The operation is not allowed for the given context.","trigger":{"stringValue":"DISPLAY"},"location":{"fieldPathElements":[{"fieldName":"operations","index":0},{"fieldName":"create"},{"fieldName":"audience_setting"},{"fieldName":"use_audience_grouped"}]}}],"requestId":""}]}}
